# How do I set div like table with different width?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have div to look like table, this is my code:

```css
.cell {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell
}

.tableLike {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: table
}

.rowLike {
  display: table-row
}

.rowLike .cell:nth-child(1),
.rowLike .cell:nth-child(3) {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableLike ">
  <div class="rowLike">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="title">PRODUCT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="title">PRICE</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rowLike">
    <div class="cell">
      <i class="icon-close">X</i>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell bolder">
      $30
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowLike">
    <div class="cell">
      <i class="icon-close">X</i>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell bolder">
      $8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now all the the columns are in different width, and I don't know why. I want that div get different width but synchronize.

Comment: Why don't you use the official HTML `<table>` tag for this ?

Comment: I prefer divs, don't like to use table if I could use div

Comment: If you have tabular data, use `table`. Otherwise, use `div`. Your content looks like you have tabular data, so it would be a bad approach to use `div`s instead of a `table`.

Comment: Tables used create a layout is considered bad practise. However it's fine to use tables to display data. That is what they are made for.

Comment: @connexo you have edited the question with answer? or something else OP is looking?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @connexo what i am telling is, when you edited the question, you have added the following styles in the css `display:table`, `display:table-cell`, `display:table-row`. When the question asked, It is not there in the OP code. Now the accepted answer and the question have the same code. You got what I am saying??

Comment: OP did this himself. I only tidied his code.

Comment: oh...i thought you did that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using display:table like this

```
.tableLike{width:100%;display:table;}
.cell{border:1px solid red;display:table-cell;}
```

```css
.tableLike {display:table;}
.rowLike{display:table-row;}
.cell{border:1px solid red;display:table-cell;}
.tableLike{padding-bottom: 30px;}
.rowLike .cell:nth-child(1),.rowLike .cell:nth-child(3){ width: 15%;}
```

```html
<div class="tableLike ">
    <div class="rowLike">
        <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="title">PRODUCT</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="title">PRICE</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowLike">
            <div class="cell">
                <i class="icon-close">X</i>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                some content
            </div>
            <div class="cell bolder">
               $30
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowLike">
            <div class="cell">
                <i class="icon-close">X</i>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                some content some content
            </div>
            <div class="cell bolder">
                $8
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the correct display styles:

```css
.cell {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
}

.tableLike {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: table;
}

.rowLike {
  display: table-row;
}

.rowLike .cell:nth-child(1),
.rowLike .cell:nth-child(3) {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableLike ">
  <div class="rowLike">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="title">PRODUCT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="title">PRICE</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rowLike">
    <div class="cell">
      <i class="icon-close">X</i>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell bolder">
      $30
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowLike">
    <div class="cell">
      <i class="icon-close">X</i>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell bolder">
      $8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tableLike {display:table;}
.rowLike{display:table-row;}
.cell{border:1px solid red;display:table-cell;}
.tableLike{padding-bottom: 30px;}
.rowLike .cell:nth-child(1),.rowLike .cell:nth-child(3){ width: 33%;}
```

```html
<div class="tableLike ">
    <div class="rowLike">
        <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="title">PRODUCT</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="title">PRICE</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowLike">
            <div class="cell">
                <i class="icon-close">X</i>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                some content
            </div>
            <div class="cell bolder">
               $30
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowLike">
            <div class="cell">
                <i class="icon-close">X</i>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                some content some content
            </div>
            <div class="cell bolder">
                $8
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do like this.
You can try, but it may not be the best answer.

```css
.cell {
  border-right:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  display: table-cell
}

.tableLike {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: table
}

.rowLike {
  display: table-row
}

.rowLike .cell:nth-child(1),
.rowLike .cell:nth-child(3) {
  width: 15%;
}

.rowLike:nth-child(1) .cell:nth-child(1),
.rowLike:nth-child(1) .cell:nth-child(2),
.rowLike:nth-child(1) .cell:nth-child(3){
  border-top:1px solid red;
}

.rowLike:nth-child(1) .cell:nth-child(1),
.icon-close{
  border-left:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableLike ">
  <div class="rowLike">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="title">PRODUCT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="title">PRICE</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rowLike">
    <div class="cell">
      <i class="icon-close">X</i>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell bolder">
      $30
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowLike">
    <div class="cell">
      <i class="icon-close">X</i>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell bolder">
      $8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```